# JSON Exception does not make sense within pyqt5 QThread environment

Tags: json, python-3.x, pyqt5, qthread

I get a JSON exception within my QThreads demo. I think it has to do with my conversion of a PyQt4 demo into a PyQt5 demo along with my lack of experience with QThreads in general.  Can someone look over this code a see if they can see any obvious problem?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

"""
Created on Thu Oct 12 12:45:13 2017
Updated Oct 24, 2017v for handing windows 7 urllib.response error

@author: Ron F

Notes:
Does not work well on Windows 7
Tested by others to work on Linux
"""
#  reference: https://nikolak.com/pyqt-threading-tutorial/

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, pyqtSignal
import sys

import urllib.request
from urllib.error import URLError, HTTPError
import json


# load the GUI design
qtCreatorFile = 'design.ui'  # Enter file here.
Ui_MainWindow, QtBaseClass = uic.loadUiType(qtCreatorFile)


class getPostsThread(QThread):
    add_post = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, subreddits):
        """
        Make a new thread instance with the specified
        subreddits as the first argument. The subreddits argument
        will be stored in an instance variable called subreddits
        which then can be accessed by all other class instance functions

        :param subreddits: A list of subreddit names
        :type subreddits: list
        """
        QThread.__init__(self)
        self.subreddits = subreddits

    #    def __del__(self):
    #        print("__del__ function called")
    #        a = self.wait()
    #        print ("a", a)

    def _get_top_post(self, subreddit):
        """
        Return a pre-formatted string with top post title, author,
        and subreddit name from the subreddit passed as the only required
        argument.

        :param subreddit: A valid subreddit name
        :type subreddit: str
        :return: A string with top post title, author,
                    and subreddit name from that subreddit.
        :rtype: str
        """
        url = "https://www.reddit.com/r/{}.json?limit=1".format(subreddit)
        headers = {'User-Agent': 'nikolak@outlook.com tutorial code'}
        request = urllib.request.Request(url, headers=headers)

        # catch request for subreddits that don't exist
        try:
            response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
        except HTTPError as e:
            print('The server couldn\'t fulfill the request.')
            print('Error code: ', e.code)
            return "NOT FOUND: " + subreddit
        except URLError as e:
            print('We failed to reach a server.')
            print('Reason: ', e.reason)
            return "URLError"
        else:
            s = str(response.info())
            if s.find("Content-Type: application/json;") != -1:
                # catch json errors
                try:
                    data = json.load(response)
                except Exception as e:
                    print("Json Exception as: ", e)
                    return "Error: Json Exception"
                else:
                    top_post = data['data']['children'][0]['data']
                    return "'{title}' by {author} in {subreddit}".format(**top_post)

        return "Error: urllib response Content-Type is not application/json"

    def run(self):
        """
        Go over every item in the self.subreddits list 
        (which was supplied during __init__)
        and for every item assume it's a string with valid subreddit
        name and fetch the top post using the _get_top_post method
        from reddit. Store the result in a local variable named
        top_post and then emit a pyqtSignal add_post(QString) where
        QString is equal to the top_post variable that was set by the
        _get_top_post function.

        """
        for subreddit in self.subreddits:
            print('run subreddit')
            print(subreddit)
            top_post = self._get_top_post(subreddit)
            # self.emit(pyqtSignal('add_post(QString)'), top_post)
            print("top_post in run")
            print(top_post)
            self.add_post.emit(top_post)
            self.sleep(2)


class ThreadingTutorial(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    """
    How the basic structure of PyQt GUI code looks and behaves is
    explained in this tutorial 
    http://nikolak.com/pyqt-qt-designer-getting-started/
    """

    def __init__(self):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.btn_start.clicked.connect(self.start_getting_top_posts)

        # initialize list of subreddits
        self.get_thread = []

    def start_getting_top_posts(self):
        # Get the subreddits user entered into an QLineEdit field
        # this will be equal to '' if there is no text entered
        subreddit_list = str(self.edit_subreddits.text()).split(',')
        if subreddit_list == ['']:
            QtWidgets.QMessageBox.critical(self, "No subreddits",
                                           "You didn't enter any subreddits.",
                                           QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Ok)
            return

        # Set the maximum value of progress bar, can be any int and it will
        # be automatically converted to x/100% values
        # e.g. max_value = 3, current_value = 1, the progress bar will show 33%
        self.progressBar.setMaximum(len(subreddit_list))
        self.progressBar.setValue(0)

        # We have a list of subreddits which we use to create a new getPostsThread
        # instance and we pass that list to the thread
        self.get_thread = getPostsThread(subreddit_list)

        # Next we need to connect the events from that thread to functions we want
        # to be run when those signals get fired

        # Adding post will be handeled in the add_post method and the signal that
        # the thread will emit is  SIGNAL("add_post(QString)")
        # the rest is same as we can use to connect any signal
        self.get_thread.add_post.connect(self.add_post)

        # Regardless of whether the thread finishes or the user terminates it
        # we want to show the notification to the user that adding is done
        # and regardless of whether it was terminated or finished by itself
        # the finished signal will go off.
        self.get_thread.finished.connect(self.done)

        self.get_thread.start()
        self.btn_stop.setEnabled(True)
        self.btn_stop.clicked.connect(self.get_thread.terminate)
        self.btn_start.setEnabled(False)

    def add_post(self, post_text):
        """
        Add the text that's given to this function to the
        list_submissions QListWidget we have in our GUI and
        increase the current value of progress bar by 1

        :param post_text: text of the item to add to the list
        :type post_text: str
        """
        print("add_post")
        self.list_submissions.addItem(post_text)
        self.progressBar.setValue(self.progressBar.value() + 1)

    def done(self):
        """
        Show the message that fetching posts is done.
        Disable Stop button, enable the Start one and reset progress bar to 0
        """
        self.btn_stop.setEnabled(False)
        self.btn_start.setEnabled(True)
        self.progressBar.setValue(0)
        QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(self, "Done!", "Done fetching posts!")


def main():
    # Only one app can exist at a time, so check before creating one.
    # Solves this error: Kernel died, restarting
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication.instance()
    if app is None:
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    form = ThreadingTutorial()
    form.show()

    # in development shell so sys.exit does not make sense    
    if sys.__stdin__.isatty():
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
    else:
        app.exec_()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This is my design.ui file as used in the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>526</width>
    <height>373</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Threading Tutorial - nikolak.com</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
    <item>
     <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="subreddits_input_layout">
      <item>
       <widget class="QLabel" name="label_subreddits">
        <property name="text">
         <string>Subreddits:</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item>
       <widget class="QLineEdit" name="edit_subreddits">
        <property name="placeholderText">
         <string>python,programming,linux,etc (comma separated)</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </item>
    <item>
     <widget class="QLabel" name="label_submissions_list">
      <property name="text">
       <string>Submissions:</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item>
     <widget class="QListWidget" name="list_submissions"/>
    </item>
    <item>
     <widget class="QProgressBar" name="progressBar">
      <property name="value">
       <number>0</number>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item>
     <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="buttons_layout">
      <item>
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="btn_stop">
        <property name="enabled">
         <bool>false</bool>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>Stop</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item>
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="btn_start">
        <property name="text">
         <string>Start</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

This is my GUI output[image]

Finally, here is my print statements during this run...

```
run subreddit
python
top_post in run
'/r/Python official Job Board!' by aphoenix in Python
add_post
run subreddit
 python
top_post in run
Error: urllib response Content-Type is not application/json
add_post
run subreddit
 python
top_post in run
Error: urllib response Content-Type is not application/json
add_post

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: I tried it and it works correctly:  https://imgur.com/a/62fga Maybe it is a configuration of your network, try another machine.

Comment: This problem has nothing to do with PyQt, I think this problem is perhaps due to a firewall or something similar. Try other pcs and other networks.

Comment: My terminal output: `$ python main.py 
run subreddit
python
response len:  51 <htt
top_post in run
'/r/Python official Job Board!' by aphoenix in Python
add_post
run subreddit
python
response len:  51 <htt
top_post in run
'/r/Python official Job Board!' by aphoenix in Python
add_post
run subreddit
python
response len:  51 <htt
top_post in run
'/r/Python official Job Board!' by aphoenix in Python
add_post`

Comment: The line `print("response len: ",len(str(response)),str(response)[:4] )` does not do what you think it does. The response is a [HTTPResponse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html#httpresponse-objects) object, not a string. So `str(response)` will always evaluate to something like `'<http.client.HTTPResponse object at 0x7f6b6c191080>'`. The json error is telling you that the response is empty for the second and third requests. To debug this properly, you should test the `urllib` code on its own, without all the threading/gui stuff. This should help isolate the problem.

Comment: PS: I cannot reproduce the problem either - but I am testing on linux (as is the other commenter). It's possible that `urllib` behaves differently on windows *vs* linux. You might want to give the [requests package](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) a try, to see if that changes anything. (You could also use Qt's networking APIs, but that would be a little more difficult to adapt to your example).

Comment: Thank you ekhumoro and eyllanesc for your comments, they were both helpful.  I have found that testing the code to retrieve subreddits works fine when qthreads library is not used. With Qthreads library used, the urllib.response() returns JSON formatted data on first call, and text formatted data on every other call - which in-turn kills the json.encode() call.  I will work on replacing my urlllib response code to something from qtnetwork so I can continue to use as I have concluded that urllib is not supported well with qthread library on Windows 7.